# How to modify the subplots in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I wanted a 7x3xi subplot. After using this code below:

```
subplot(7,3,1)
    figure(1);
    hold on;
scatter(x,y,12,'k','filled');

[pp,s] = polyfit(x,y,1);
r_squared = 1 - s.normr^2 / norm(x-mean(y))^2;
str = {sprintf('y = %.2fx+%.2f',pp(1),pp(2)),sprintf('R^2 = %.2f',r_squared)};
annotation('textbox', [0.2, 0.75, .1, .1], 'String',str ,'FitBoxToText',...
    'on','fontname','Cambria Math','HorizontalAlignment', 'center',...
    'FontSize',8,'BackgroundColor', 'white');
xlabel('Observed precipitation (mm)','FontSize',8)
ylabel('Modeled precipitation (mm)','FontSize',8)
set(gca,'fontname','Times New Roman','FontSize',8)  % Set it to times
box on;
grid on
hTrend = refline(pp(1), pp(2)); % Trend line
hrefline = refline([1 0]); % 45 degree refline
hrefline.Color = 'k';
axis normal
```

I saw this figure:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17MsC.jpg)
(repeat this code for all (7x3xi) You can see more than very bad and with subplots I saw my annotation for each plot disappear and just one annotation exist !
I want to make my support something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0481p.jpg). I would be grateful if you can tell me what option I have. Best Regards.

Comment: To make it easier for contributors, can you add an example of variables needed? like `x` and `y`. Also, do you make `i` go from 1 to 21? Since you want to plot 7*3=21 different graphs, it is important to make `i` work in that interval.

Comment: Remove the `figure(1)` call, it likely messes up things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to create plots with subplots, you need to use a loop, using the following pseudo-code structure. the key is to call subplot(nx,ny,idx) to activate each subplot as your canvas to draw.

```
figure;
nx=7; ny=3;
for i=1:nx
   for j=1:ny
      subplot(nx,ny,i*ny+j); hold on;
      scatter(...);
      polyfit(...);
      annotation(...);
   end
end
```